# Use dlib in Visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dlib

I want to use optimization algorithm lbfgs in my project but I do not want to code it myself. So I found `Dlib` is a good option.

http://dlib.net/compile.html is a good library. I downloaded it. I use windows 7 and visual studio 2012. If I create a new win 32 console project and set `property->configuration properties->VC++ Directories->Include Directories` to the path of `Dlib`(dlib-18.10/).

[image]

And it works fine which mean I can run examples.

But when I add it to my project. I occur errors.(`error : "vector" is ambiguous`)

I guess it maybe because the way I include it.

On the document of `Dlib`, it says,

`Again, note that you should not add the dlib folder itself to your compiler's include path. Doing so will cause the build to fail because of name collisions (such as dlib/string.h and string.h from the standard library). Instead you should add the folder that contains the dlib folder to your include search path and then use include statements of the form #include <dlib/queue.h>. This will ensure that everything builds correctly.`

But I am not clear what it means above. I googled `the Visual Studio search path (Tools / Options / Projects and Solutions / VC++ Directories).`. But in my project this is non-editable.

I only use optimization.h in dlib. If I delete 'using namespace dlib;', then ' typedef matrix column_vector;'then the error is `matrix` is not a template. If I keep 'using namespace dlib;' I have error "vector" is ambiguous`.

```
#include <dlib/optimization.h>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
using namespace dlib;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// In dlib, the general purpose solvers optimize functions that take a column
// vector as input and return a double.  So here we make a typedef for a
// variable length column vector of doubles.  This is the type we will use to
// represent the input to our objective functions which we will be minimizing.
typedef matrix<double,0,1> column_vector;
```

Comment: You should not point the directory where all the headers are, but one step up. Then, you will include your headers as #include <dlib/vector.h>.

Comment: @HalilKaskavalci, Thank you for your comment. I am not sure with header I will use. I use the vector from c++. And as you mentioned, in Dlib itself has the file vector.h. But should I add #include <dlib/vector.h>, since I use `vector ` from C++ std?

Comment: OK I understand your problem now. First thing is, whenever you want to include something from std, you just include as `#include <vector.h>`. Let's say you want dlib's vector which reside under geometry. Then you should include `#include <dlib/geometry/vector.h>`. Whenever you want to use them, you should specify the namespace, because that is also confusing for the compiler. If you have both std and dlib namespace used in your program, you should say `std::vector` or `dlib::vector` whenever you use them. Hope that helps!

Comment: @HalilKaskavalci, thank you. This helps. I hope this could work at least. But it is manually.

Comment: I posted as an answer as well. Enjoy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation says, include directory should be root directory of the zip you downloaded. Then you include as `#include <dlib/vector.h>`. However, since vector is defined under namespace of std as well, you should be specifically denote which namespace's STL you will use.

If you want to use std::vector,
`#include <vector.h>`
then use it as
`std::vector<int> stdVar;`

Similarly, for dlib,
`#include <dlib/geometry/vector`
then use it as
`dlib::vector<int> dLibVar;`

You could also delete `using namespace std` if you don't use it as frequent as dlib. Then every STL you reference will be dlib. If you want std, just type `std::vector`.

Comment: I use std::vector more often. I update my question to give more detail.

Comment: The way you include the include path is correct. Basically you should remove the ambiguity by specifying namespaces. If you want remove dlib, then you should include dlib::matrix whenever you reference dlib STLs. Did I get your question right?

Answer (score 0):

```
using namespace std;
using namespace dlib;
#define vector std::vector
```

use w/ caution